# how to download file dynamically i.e a file with extension .pec is been uploaded to a sever , now i have to download the same file

Tags: php

How to download file dynamically i.e a file with extension .pec is been uploaded to a sever, now I have to download the same file without giving the name of that file with .pec extension.

In line 4th I have given the name of the file wasifresume.pdf  which I have uploaded to sever and gets encryptes to wasifresume.pec extension and now  I have to download the file same file dynamically , in line  4th

```
 $file = "wasifresume.pec";
```

without give the name of the file wasifresume

Is there any code for this like *.pec or something to download the same file because i want to make it dynamically.

```
<<?php
session_start();

ob_start();

$file = "wasifresume.pec";

echo $_SESSION["file_name"]."the name";

ob_start();
// put some business here 


if(file_exists($file))
{
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); 
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();

readfile($file);
exit;
}
else
echo "file not found";
?>
```

see the upload.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
//$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $uploadOk = 1;
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size 
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 50000000) {
echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
echo $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],   $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has   been uploaded.";
//   echo  $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]; 

   $_SESSION["file_name"]=$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
```

//   echo $_SESSION["file_name"];

```
 exec('/var/www/html/CryptCmdline http://*.*.*.*/uploads/'. $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"],$output);

    // $output=shell_exec("dr.bs");
    // print_r($output);

     include('/var/www/html/down.php');
   } else {
       echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
   }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .htacces file

```
AddType application/octet-stream .pec
```

That will make it auto downloaded

or:

```
<FilesMatch ".pec">
ForceType application/octet-stream
Header set Content-Disposition attachment
Header set Content-Description "File Transfer"
Header set Content-Transfer-Encoding "binary"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: suggest some other technique

Comment: that way is 100% working, can you tell what did you do ?

Comment: well actually In line 4th i have uploaded the file wasifresume.pdf which then gets encryptes to wasifresume.pec extension and now i have to download the file same file dynamically , in line4th$file="wasifresume.pec"; its downloading wiht this command but i want that a user should send any file like asp.png which is uploaded to server (which i have done in upload.php)which the encrpted as asp.pec at server now if i have to download the asp.pec file then i have to write 
$file = "asp.pec"; which is not dynamic . so i need the code to which user can upload the file and get the same name file.pec.

Comment: You can encrypt the file and then in your code make header('location: file.pec'); so it download the encrypted one

Comment: exec('/var/www/html/CryptCmdline http://.../uploads/'. $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"],$output);

Answer (score 0):

Setting content-type in your PHP code alone is not sufficient. You need to add PEC to your Webserver's MIME type for it to understand what kind of file it is transferring